# ScriptManager not working while adding parameters in alert in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

I want to display dynamic ID generated while inserting the record in the database in alert.

So I implemented the below mentioned code for my use.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Request has been created for Sap ID ='" + ObjIPColoFields.SAP_ID + " with Request No: '" + strReturnId + "'); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';", true);
```

But nothing is happening, but when I removed the parameters it works fine. How to make it work with parameters

Comment: Check your apostophes!

Comment: @user1429080: is it fine ? `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Request has been created for Sap ID ='" + ObjIPColoFields.SAP_ID + "' with Request No: '" + strReturnId + "'); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';", true);` tried with this, but no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some extra apos that is causing the `alert` to be broken. Assuming that `SAP_ID` is 123 and `strReturnId` is 456, the script you build is:

```
alert('Request has been created for Sap ID ='123 with Request No: '456'); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';
```

There are two extra apos here, one after `=` and one before `456`. Remove them and you have a better chance of actually seeing an alert. What you want is probably:

```
alert('Request has been created for Sap ID =123 with Request No: 456'); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';
```

Of course the end result also depends on the actual value of the `SAP_ID` and `strReturnId`. If they are strings, you need to make sure that they don't contain apos or quotes, or you need to properly escape those chars.

---

Try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Request has been created for Sap ID = " + ObjIPColoFields.SAP_ID + " with Request No: " + strReturnId + "'); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';", true);
```

Comment: tried your statement like this, but not working `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Request has been created for Sap ID: " + ObjIPColoFields.SAP_ID + " with Request No " + strReturnId + "); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';", true);`


Also my Sap_ID is `I-MH-SNGE-ENB-I016` and RequestID is `809585`

Comment: perfect, its working now.. I was removing the last `'` also. Thanks Mate